# Hello! I erroneously transferred my Ethereum coins in my Coinomi Wallet to the Ethereum CLASSIC Wallet on Cryptopia

Tags: ethereum-classic, exchanges, wallet-transfer

SO, here's the story; yesterday, I wanted to sync all my wallets to be on one exchanger and I found cryptopia to be reliable. 
But I wasn't paying attention when I generated the wallet for ETC and so I just copied the address and sent all the ETH on my Coinomi to that account. Now it's been 8 hours and I can't see a reflection of the coins anywhere. Is it possible to reverse this action?

PS: I'm new to cryptocurrencies. I'm not sure how all of this works...

Answer (score 2):

Once a transaction is final on the blockchain, there is no way to cancel or reverse it. However, if you have the private key for this address (regardless of chain) you do still have access to your account.

Start by checking your balance on etherscan.io and gastracker.io. If you see your balance, then it is just a matter of accessing that wallet on the correct chain in order to see and spend your ETH.

If you have the private key to this account, you can use MyEtherWallet to access that wallet on either chain. You can select which chain you are on via the node switcher in the upper right corner of https://www.myetherwallet.com/.

If you do not have the key because the funds are in a service, reach out to them and explain the situation. It may be possible that they can send your ETH/ETC to a different account.